# jqgrid Posting Jqgrid Data back to Action class

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

```
    var mydata = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
    var paras=new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<mydata.length;i++){
        var row=mydata[i];
        paras.push($.param(row));
     }
    paras = paras.join('&');
   jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{postData:paras});

$("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:'portfolioStValidate.action'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

I'm in an urgent need of help related to jqgrid. I have a requirement to createa jqgrid where user can edit the rows and save the complete set of data back to database. For passing jqgrid data back to java action class I'm using the code above. 
i am not getting all the records back to my Java class. My grid has 42 columns and around 800 rows .
In my Java Action I'm always getting only 271 rows.
Can anyone help please?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

i found below ways to post large data of grid back to server may be it will be helpful for some.

```
var mydata = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');

var paras=new Array();

paras = JSON.stringify(mydata);
//jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{data:paras});  
//$("#list").setGridParam({ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }});
$("#list").setGridParam({datatype: 'json'}); 

jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{postData:{value:paras}});
//$("#list").setGridParam({ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }});

$("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:'portfolioStValidate.action'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

One json2.js file i have added